# Determining characteristics of the differential equation based on the behavior of its solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve this problem, and I have some ideas of how to do it, but I can't quite pin it down.

> All the solutions to the equation: $$x''+p(t)x'+q(t)x=0$$
> tend to $0$ as $t$ tends to $0$. What can be said about $p(t)$?

I have tried drawing all the different ways I can think of that a function can tend to zero (decreasing oscillations, or something like $e^{-x}$ or $-e^{-x}$.) From there, I can find some relationships between $x$, $x'$, and $x''$. For example, if the function is positive, it must at some point start to decrease, but that decrease must eventually slow down, or else the function becomes negative. And if it's negative, it must at some point start to increase and then the increase slows down.

From that sort of analysis, I think I've concluded at least that $p(t)$ is bounded from below, but I'm not sure if that's sufficient, and I haven't proved it rigorously at all, I've just drawn some pictures.

Does anyone have an idea of a theorem that might be applicable here, or of a more rigorous way of approaching this? I have a sense that Gronwall's Inequality might be applicable, but I don't know exactly how.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean to say that all solutions tend to $0$ as $t$ (not $x$) tends to $0$?  Because saying solutions tend to $0$ as $x$ (which is itself a solution) doesn't tell us much.  With my suggested reading a very nice question!  ***Endorsed, +1!!! Cheers!***

Comment: Oh yes my bad! Thank you for catching it.

Comment: Thanks for fixing it!  ***Cheers!!!***

Comment: I am not certain, but it feels like we need some more information about the solutions; specifically, if they are analytic near $0$